# Move submitted files in drive to another folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms, drive

I'm trying to send a submitted images to unique subfolder any time some user send images through my google form, this is my code so far :

```
var idnumber = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'America/Bogota', 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss')

function onFormSubmit(e) {  
    var driveMainFolder = 'MyFolder'
    var driveSubFolder = idnumber;    

// Create subfolder
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveMainFolder).next();
    var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(driveSubFolder);  

// Move files to subfolder
    var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveMainFolder).next().getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var destination = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveSubFolder).next();
        destination.addFile(file);
        var pull = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveMainFolder).next();
        pull.removeFile(file);
    }     
}
```

It kind of works, after sending the images some of these images stay in "MyFolder" instead of moving directly to the unique subfolder.

- This trigger is being called in the event OnFormSubmit, is created in the Google Form Spreadsheet.
- In "my Executions" the trigger doesn't display anything wrong but not the whole images moves to unique subfolder.
- I'm sending 5 images, in average each one has 18kb.

Is there a way to upload images from a Google Form and add a trigger to organize the images ? Thanks !

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about putting `Utilities.sleep(5000)` after the line of `function onFormSubmit(e) {`? Because I thought that the file might be not completely created yet when the form was submitted. I'm not sure whether `5000` is the best for your situation. If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. By the way, what means of `a trigger to organize the images`?

Comment: I edited the code in your question to remove some redundancy you had, you were declaring the root folder in three separate places, there was no need for that. You should test out Taniake's suggestion of using `sleep()`. Lastly, when you add the file to `newFolder` you don't need to assign it to a variable, since you're not doing anything else afterwards, so that line should just be `newFolder.addFile(file);`

Comment: That would be a pretty good solution, but the requests the users are sending might be in a few seconds, so i would afraid to move some images from other user directly to a folder is not it, so sleep it's a possible solution but not in context.

The trigger would be this code on the event "OnFormSubmit" to move the images, thanks @Tanaike

Comment: @Frederik LeBlanc Thank you for replying. The OnSubmit event trigger is run as owner. So when an user submit the form and the trigger is fired, the script is run as the owner who is you. How about this? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is happening, the thing is ... every time a user attach the 5 images and completes the google form, some of those images stay in MyFolder instead of moving, thanks @tanaike